# how do i make echarts resize together with the react-grid-layout?

Tags: reactjs, echarts, react-grid-layout, apache-echarts

I am using ResponsiveGridLayout, React-Grid-Layout in my application, and I am using echarts as grid items.

The drag and drop works fine, but when i resize the grid item, the chart did not resize together with it. I have tried implementing the onLayoutchange properties, but it is not working.

can someone can help me out here

this is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grid-layout-with-resizable-forked-z3wd9?file=/src/index.js) that reproduce the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve this, at least when modifying grid items width (not height yet...), by using [this hook](https://github.com/rehooks/component-size), then in your chart component :

```
[...]

const chartRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
const size = useComponentSize(chartRef);

useEffect(() => {
  const chart = chartRef.current && echarts.getInstanceByDom(chartRef.current);
  if (chart) {
    chart.resize();
  }
}, [size]);

[...]

return <div ref={chartRef}></div>;
```

...so your chart will resize when the grid item is resized. I'm not sure about that, still a WIP for me but it works.

### Extract this as a custom hook

You can create `useEchartResizer.ts`, based on [@rehooks/component-size](https://github.com/rehooks/component-size#readme) :

```js
import useComponentSize from '@rehooks/component-size';
import * as echarts from 'echarts';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    
export const useEchartResizer = (chartRef: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>) => {
  const size = useComponentSize(chartRef);
   
  useEffect(() => {
    const chart = chartRef.current && echarts.getInstanceByDom(chartRef.current);
    if (chart) {
      chart.resize();
    }
  }, [chartRef, size]);
};
```

Then use it in the component which holds the chart :

```js
export const ComponentWithChart = (props): React.ReactElement => {
  const chartRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  useEchartResizer(chartRef);

  useEffect(() => {
    const chart = echarts.init(chartRef.current, null);
    // do not set chart height in options
    // but you need to ensure that the containing div is not "flat" (height = 0)
    chart.setOption({...} as EChartsOption); 
  });

  return (<div ref={chartRef}></div>);
});
```

So each time the div is resized, `useEchartResizer` will trigger a `chart.resize()`. Works well with react-grid-layout.

Comment: Sorry I won't have the time to setup a codesandbox for this, just throwing the main ideas of my WIP...

Comment: for this part `const chartRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();` so i will be passing from my index.js to my chart component?

Comment: This part allows you to get the chart instance through a React Ref (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), so you can trigger a resize on the chart when the component is resized (using react-grid-layout). This is done with a useEffect, triggered when "size" (which is the actual dimensions of the component) changes.

Comment: as in how do i get HTMLDivElement? since my chart component is functional component, the only way i see how its going to get a HTMLDivElement, is index.js pass it as props

Comment: This is the type of the element which will be targeted by the ref, so here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement. You can forget about this if you prefer : const chartRef = useRef();. See https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-use-react-useref-with-typescript for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236716/discussion-between-user14857732-and-florian-motteau).